# Is there a call back available for when a Z3_ast object is deleted?

Tags: z3

I am using the C++ API for z3 so I don't need to worry about reference counting or memory management.

However, I would like to store information against the z3 AST using a std::map along the lines of `std::map<Z3_ast, some_struct>`.

When a particular Z3_ast object is deleted, I would like to remove its entry
from this map.

Is there some way to set up a call back function which will be called when
a Z3_ast object reference count returns to 0 and the Z3_ast object is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such callback, but conceivable you could hack the API to provide one. However, for as long as there is a at least one reference to the `Z3_ast`, the reference count should never drop to 0 anyways (and your map holds a reference, i.e., the one in the map).

If you don't increment the reference count at the time at which a `Z3_ast` is stored in the map, the reference counting paradigm is broken out of, which will probably result in bugs that are very hard to debug.